# Multi-module Maven project Dockerfile

Tags: java, maven, dockerfile

I try write Dockerfile for multi module maven project.
I have 5 modules. 2 modules contain only dependencies.
I parted Dockerfile for 3 steps.
Base, deps(dependencies) and builder.
I have problem with deps.

Locally when I run
`mvn -B -e org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.0:go-offline`
all steps are success

```
[INFO] core ............................................... SUCCESS [  0.248 s]
[INFO] dispatcher ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.146 s]
[INFO] repository ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.130 s]
[INFO] worker ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.137 s]
[INFO] api ................................................ SUCCESS [  0.219 s]
```

But, when I execute the same command from Dockerfile:

```
FROM amazoncorretto:8 AS base

FROM maven:3-amazoncorretto-8 as deps
WORKDIR /appbuild
COPY pom.xml pom.xml
COPY core/pom.xml core/pom.xml
COPY dispatcher/pom.xml dispatcher/pom.xml
COPY worker/pom.xml worker/pom.xml
COPY repository/pom.xml repository/pom.xml
COPY api/pom.xml api/pom.xml
RUN mvn -B -e org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.0:go-offline
```

I receive:

```
11:34:16  #18 15.00 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project dispatcher: Could not resolve dependencies for project pl.mycustom:dispatcher:jar:1.0: Could not find artifact pl.mycustom:core:jar:1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
11:34:16  #18 15.00 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal on project dispatcher: Could not resolve dependencies for project pl.mycustom:dispatcher:jar:1.0: Could not find artifact pl.mycustom:core:jar:1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
11:34:16  #18 15.00     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.getDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:269)
11:34:16  #18 15.00     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies (LifecycleDependencyResolver.java:147)
11:34:16  #18 15.00     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.ensureDependenciesAreResolved (MojoExecutor.java:401)


11:34:16  #18 15.00 [INFO] website-automation-rule-cluster .................... SUCCESS [  9.809 s]
11:34:16  #18 15.00 [INFO] core ............................................... SUCCESS [  2.682 s]
11:34:16  #18 15.00 [INFO] dispatcher ......................................... FAILURE [  0.879 s]
11:34:16  #18 15.00 [INFO] repository ......................................... SKIPPED
11:34:16  #18 15.00 [INFO] worker ............................................. SKIPPED
11:34:16  #18 15.00 [INFO] api ................................................ SKIPPED
11:34:16  #18 15.00 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
11:34:16  #18 15.00 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Why is it working locally but not from Dockerfile ?

Moreover I tried with different versions of the plugins apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:go-offline.
e.g
apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:go-offline.
But errors was different depending on version.
With apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:go-offline and higher
Errors was the same locally mvn go:offline and from Dockerfile.

```
16:13:16  #18 27.61 [INFO] website-automation-rule-cluster .................... SUCCESS [ 15.759 s]
16:13:16  #18 27.61 [INFO] core ............................................... SUCCESS [  2.433 s]
16:13:16  #18 27.61 [INFO] dispatcher ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.761 s]
16:13:16  #18 27.61 [INFO] repository ......................................... SUCCESS [  3.528 s]
16:13:16  #18 27.61 [INFO] worker ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.088 s]
16:13:16  #18 27.61 [INFO] api ................................................ FAILURE [  3.421 s]
#20 360.8 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:go-offline (default-cli) on project api: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.testng:testng:jar:6.12 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
#20 360.8 org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:go-offline (default-cli) on project api: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.testng:testng:jar:6.12 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)
```

I checked pom.xml every module. I didn't find testng dependency.

Answer (score 0):

that is actually sad :(

> Could not find artifact pl.mycustom:core:jar:1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

This one (according to naming convention) seems to be cached in your local ~/.m2/repository (or/and stored in the enterprise one) which is not available in docker container, i.e. if it stored in enterprise repository you need to setup maven in docker container (provide correct ~/.m2/setting.xml)

> Could not find artifact org.testng:testng:jar:6.12 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

This one is even more problematic: testng-6.12 has never been deployed to maven central, but it seems there are plugin dependencies in you project which uses it :(

Could you tell what is your target goal? Just if you need to collect project's dependencies in single place and this is one-time activity is is possible to load dependencies from your ~/.m2/repository, smth. like:

1. setup ~/.m2/seettings.xml - set you local cache as a mirror

```
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>internal-repository</id>
            <name>Dummy repository</name>
            <url>!!!file:///Users/apanfilov/.m2/repository!!!</url>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
```

2. execute something like `mvn de.qaware.maven:go-offline-maven-plugin:1.2.8:resolve-dependencies -Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository` to copy all project related dependencies to another folder.